# OpenVPN client connects but no internet access, even though I masquerade

Tags: iptables, openvpn, port-forwarding

I installed openvpn server at home on centos 7. using [digital ocean doc](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-and-configure-an-openvpn-server-on-centos-7).

`ip route` showed my server's network interface is ens32.
so I added a rule to iptables to forward routing to OpenVPN subnet

`iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o ens32 -j MASQUERADE`

I also have google's DNS in my server config.

`push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"`

and I also configured the server to tell the clients to redirect all traffic through the OpenVPN.

`push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"`

and I am doing this at home internet, so on the router I did port forwarding on openvpn's port.

on my android phone, the openvpn client app successfully logs in  to the server and it gets a private ip (10.8.0.6) and it shows a few KB been sent and received, and it is green and happy ! but it can NOT access internet.

I have been trying so many different things, I have no idea why it can't access internet.

the openvpn server itself I checked by `curl google.com` that it does have access to internet.

any idea?

Comment: Full configs? Logs? Route tables?

Comment: @MichalSokolowski I didnt change anything else other than the ones I posted above, (plus I enbabled ipv4 forwarding)

Comment: @MichalSokolowski here is my full server config anyways https://gist.github.com/medyagh/3dba362436fc8e1b0e7cbd7e4d20a45b

Comment: @MichalSokolowski this is my client ovpn without the actual keys https://gist.github.com/medyagh/a19be7cd3318803cf93bb1bfabb80a57

Comment: the only thing I see in the journalctl -xe is  `client/MYPUBLICHOMEIP:39661 IP packet with unknown IP version=15 seen`

Comment: @Madya, as a sysadmin with almost decade experience with OpenVPN; networking problems are hard to diagnose remotely in the first place, without full picture it's almost impossible or it'd take too much time. I won't be able to help without it. Possibly others too.

Comment: @Madya, See? Power of the logs. With verb 3 you had direct clue for sure in OpenVPN's client log that compression option was different on the server side.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70606/discussion-between-medya-and-michal-sokolowski).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally found the problem and the solution, I saw this message in `journalctl -xe` for (openvpn server logs)

`client/__MYPUBLICHOMEIP__:39661 IP packet with unknown IP version=15 seen`

Then I realized on my client default configuration compression was enabled but the server side the compression was not enabled.

uncommenting this line in the openvpn server's conf fixed the problem:

`comp-lzo`